# "Undefined" button when I try to save a table in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am new with phpMyAdmin but I want to learn so I make a table with diferent values (float, varchar, decimal, int, boolean). I also have an ID field as a primary key with A_I and cotejamiento (utf8 spanish ci) but when I try to save it appears a red "Undefined" button. What am I doing wrong.

Thank you all.

Comment: Please give your table structure query.

Comment: Hi Nikul, Here you have: https://mega.co.nz/#!SJM3kB4L!NiU1iTIQ7xhdsKR_LPoXkWdLwo-F2b7NX4mm6zxiSq0

Comment: I already fixed it, I did the table by parts, 10 columns each time. Thanks

Comment: it's a horrible bug in phpmyadmin ..